# Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 extraction error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

We are planning to use SSRS for reporting, using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012.  i've tried a few times to download the plugin from Microsoft's site:
[Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

After downloading whenever I try to run the exe I get an extraction failed message, doesn't say anything else about the error.  I'm running Windows 7 64bit, have .Net 4.5.1 installed.  Has anyone been able to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We resolved the issue, our anti-virus was blocking the extraction.  Disabled the anti-virus and it extracted and installed fine.